# How do I iterate through two arrays and print user input?

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, iteration

I am trying to prompt a user for full names, and then encrypt them.

I have a loop that will continue asking the user for names until they type `'quit'`.  Upon `'quit'`, I need to print sentences containing both the `real_name` and the `encrypt_name` for each name.

I have an array to push the user's name to. An example with three names:

```
full_name = ["Fred Fredrickson", "Bobby June", "Jack Daniel"]
```

I assume I should then push the encrypted names to a separate array. An example array of these three names after encryption:

```
encrypt_name = ["Gsifsodltup Gsif", "Kapi Cuccz", "Fepoim Kedl"]
```

I need to print this statement for each name:

```
puts "The spy #{full_name} now has an encrypted name of #{encrypt_name}"
```

How do I iterate through the arrays and print the data in this statement for every name? Is there a different/better way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Switching first and last names and shifting by one letter does maybe not really qualify as encryption as much as obfuscation ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two basic methods:

a) Make each person a class, keeping all the data in one place, so you can have just one array:

a1) Using proper class:

```
class Person
  attr_reader :full_name, encrypt_name

  def initialize(full_name, encrypt_name)
    self.full_name = full_name
    self.encrypt_name = encrypt_name
  end
end

people = []
loop do
  full_name = gets.chomp
  break if full_name == "quit"
  people << Person.new(full_name, encrypt(full_name))
end
people.each do |person|
  puts "The spy #{person.full_name} now has an encrypted name of #{person.encrypt_name}"
end
```

a2) The class is so simple we can define it using `Struct`:

```
Person = Struct.new(:full_name, :encrypt_name)
```

a3) If you can't be bothered, you can just use a mini-array `[full_name, encrypt_name]`, or a hash `{ full_name: full_name, encrypt_name: encrypt_name }`, but those are not as readable.

b) If you really want to iterate two arrays, use `Array#zip`:

```
full_names.zip(encrypt_names).each do |full_name, encrypt_name|
  puts "The spy #{full_name} now has an encrypted name of #{encrypt_name}"
end
```